# Rails: Can't save file from URL and save it to Amazon S3 (S3::Error::ResponseError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to save file from a URL and then save it to S3. This is the rake task code that I've written:

```
require 's3'
require 'open-uri'

task :testing => [:environment] do
  aws_object = S3::Service.new(access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id, secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key)
  bucket = aws_object.buckets.find(Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket)
  url = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1111729635610382336/_65QFl7B_400x400.png'
  downloded_file = open(url)

  new_file = bucket.objects.build('twitter.jpg')
  new_file.content = (File.read downloded_file)

  if new_file.save
    puts "Success!"
  end
end
```

But when I run this rake task code above, this is what I got on my terminal:

```
rake aborted!
S3::Error::ResponseError: S3::Error::ResponseError
/Users/ryzal/Sites/test/lib/tasks/testing.rake:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/ryzal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/ryzal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => testing
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've checked all my S3 details and all are correct. Can somebody help?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the error and see what is really happening.

    `begin
      # your code  
    rescue Exception => e  
      e.response.inspect  
    end`

Comment: No idea about your version of the aws sdk, but s3 now always needs the region of your S3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved this and this is how I did it:

1) I use [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem instead of `s3` gem

2) I refer S3 documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html) and renew my code to this:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
require 'open-uri'

task :testing => [:environment] do
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region)
  obj = s3.bucket(Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket).object("any_unique_key_you_want_such_as_email_or_username")

  url = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1111729635610382336/_65QFl7B_400x400.png'
  file = open(url)

  obj.put(body: file, acl: "public-read")

  puts "URL is: #{obj.public_url}"
end
```